# Error "express_1 is not defined" on NestJS unit tests

Tags: node.js, express, unit-testing, nestjs, multer

I have a NestJS app that uploads files to Cloudinary a.o. - the controller method comes straight from NestJS documentation, and it works perfectly.

```
  import { Express } from 'express';       // <<< (1) removed this in answer below
  ...
  ...
  @Post('/upload/image')
  @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file'))
  uploadImage(@UploadedFile() file: Express.Multer.File,
              @Request() request: any) {
    return this.cloudinaryService.uploadFile(file, {
      environment: request.query.environment,
      domain: request.query.domain,
      path: request.query.path,
      name: request.query.name,
    });
  }
```

However every unit test (Jest) in a module that depends on the above module fails with the error below :-

```
  ● Test suite failed to run

    ReferenceError: express_1 is not defined

      40 |   @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file'))
    > 42 |   uploadImage(@UploadedFile() file: Express.Multer.File,
         |                                     ^
      43 |               @Request() request: any) {
      44 |     return this.cloudinaryService.uploadFile(file, {
      45 |       environment: request.query.environment,

      at Object.<anonymous> (src/modules/apps/bbb/controllers/bbb.controller.ts:42:37)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/modules/apps/bbb/bbb.module.ts:3:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/modules/apps/amethyst/amethyst.module.ts:19:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/modules/apps/amethyst/providers/ccc.service.spec.ts:7:1)
```

My unit test setup looks like this - all that I can see that is relevant is that I am importing the containing module

```
  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [
        SharedModule,
        MailModule,
        AmethystModule,
        BbbModule      <<<<<
      ],
      providers: [],
    }).compile();
    ...
    ...
  });
```

As my app is functioning perfectly and my unit tests are failing, I'm assuming that I am missing something in my test setups. It feels as though I should be importing Express or MulterModule somewhere - I just don't know where or how.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have solved this problem - although I have absolutely no idea why it works.

I simply needed to remove the import of Express in the controller above (1)

```
 import { Express } from 'express';
```

even though I am referencing `Express.Multer.File` in the code. I guess it is some kind of global variable/namespace of Express that works, while specifically importing from `express` package provided an alternative and insufficient version ?

If anyone feels like explaining it (for myself and others) I would be happy to accept it as an answer.